# What kind of purifactory rite is mentioned in ayodhya kanda which uses "aiNeyaM mamsa" antelope meat?

Tags: ramayana, rituals, rama, vedic-rituals

This is mentioned in ayodhya kand-

> "aiNeyam maamsam aahR^itya shaalaam yakSyaamahe vayam | kartvyam
>   vaastushamanam saumitre cirajiivabhiH || 2-56-22
>
> 22. saumitre= Oh, Lakshmana!; aahR^itya= being; aiNeyam maamsam= bring meat of the antelope; vayam= we; yakshyaamahe= shall worship;
>       shaalaam= (this) leaf-hut; vaastushamanam= purifactory ceremony on
>       entering the house; kartavyam= on entering the; chirajiivibhiH= by
>       those who wish to live long.
>
> Oh, Lakshmana! Bring the meat of an antelope. We shall perform a
>   purifactory ceremony while entering the house. Which is to be done by
>   those who wish to live long."
>
> "mR^igam hatvaa.a.anaya kshipram lakshmaNeha shubhekshaNa kartavyaH
>   shaastradR^iSTo hi vidhirdarmamanusmara || 2-56-23
>
> 23. shubhekshaNa= Oh, large-eyed; lakshmaNa= Lakshmana!; hatvaa= killing; mR^igam= the antelope; kshhipram= quickly; anaya= bring; iha=
>       here; vidhiH= the prescribed rite; shaastra dR^iSTaH= according to
>       scriptural point of view; kartavyaH hi= indeed is to be done;
>       anusmara= keep in mind; dharmam= the sacred obligation.
>
> Oh, large-eyed Lakshmana! Killing the antelope quickly, bring it here.
>   The prescribed rite according to scriptural point of view indeed is to
>   be performed. Keep in mind the sacred obligation.”
>
> "raamaH snaatvaa tu niyataH guNavaan japya kovidaH |
>   samgraheNaakarotsarvaan mantran satraavasaanikaan || 2-56-29
>
> 29. raamaH= Rama; guNavaan= the virtuous man; japyakovidaH= and the learned man in chanting of prayers; snaatvaa= after taking bath;
>       niyataH= with subdned mind; samgraheNa= briefly; akarot= chanted;
>       sarvaan= all; mantran= the sacred scripts; satraavasaanikaan= which
>       are to be chanted at the end of a purifactory ceremony.
>
> Rama, the virtuous man and the learned man in chanting of sacred
>   spells, after taking bath and with subdued mind, briefly chanted all
>   the sacred scripts to be chanted at the end of a purifactory
>   ceremony."

What kind of purifactory rite is done with antelope meat- is this mentioned in any of the Vedic rituals?